# Escape comma(,) from a csv cell while while exporting its data to database table

Tags: c#, .net, csv, datatable, delimiter

I have a csv file in which there is a field having comma in it. e.g under office location column I have a value xyz, building. When i checked the value through debugger it only shows "\"xyz". I have tried escaping the comma and backward slash by using `Replace(",","")` and `Replace("\"","")` but it failed. Also I am getting extra `\` in the result as marked in red circle.

I have attached the image while debugging showing the structure of the csv row. The problem is in the red circle area.

[image]

I have also tried following function:

```
public static string RemoveColumnDelimitersInsideValues(string input)
    {

        const char valueDelimiter = '"';
        const char columnDelimiter = ',';

        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        bool isInsideValue = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            var currentChar = input[i];

            if (currentChar == valueDelimiter)
            {
                isInsideValue = !isInsideValue;
                output.Append(currentChar);
                continue;
            }

            if (currentChar != columnDelimiter || !isInsideValue)
            {
                output.Append(currentChar);
            }

        }
        return output.ToString();
    }
```

Kindly help in resolving the issues. Thanks

Comment: Actually, it seems to me its just in debugger view that this backslash exists. You should try to output this string to a file to see if the backslash is really here or not

Comment: The easy way would be to use a ready-written CSV parser, which will also take care of `"` inside a value, where it is escaped as `""`.

Comment: It you data has comma then you should save in a different format that comma separated value(csv).  Try using tab separated values(tsv).

Answer (score 0):

The \ character you see is not in the actual string, it's just an escaping character added in the debugger view.

Click on the magnifier to get the actual value of the string.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`String.Replace` doesn't modify the existing string, it returns a new one. Because of that, you have the same old `row` string outside `IsNullOrEmpty` check.

Also, you are telling, you are trying to escape comma and quotes, but from you are removing it in your code.

If you want to **remove** commas and quotes, your code may look like

```cs
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
{
    row = row.Replace(",", "").Replace("\"", "");
}
```

If you want to **escape** quotes and commas, your code may look like

```cs
if (row != null && row.Contains(","))
{
    row = "\"" + row.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using TextFieldParser, in csv if the column value has comma the column value is escaped with qoutes, so adding HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes to true will automatically read it as single column.

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;


using (TextFieldParser reader = new TextFieldParser(csvpath))
       {
         reader.Delimiters = new string[] { "," };
         reader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
         string[] col =  reader.ReadFields();
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 issues with your code that are worth pointing out.

## 1. Parsing a CSV can be tricky

Would you code handle a multiline string correctly? Would you code handle a `"` inside one of the columns (so an escaped `"`)?

I recommend using a csv reading libary (aka NuGet package).

## There is no backslash

Here is a file.

```
1,"The string in the first row has a comma, and an f, in it"
2,The string in the 2nd row does not have a comma in it
```

Here is what Visual Studio shows (I'm using VS Code here).

[image]

Here is what Console.WriteLine prints.

```
1,"The string in the first row has a comma, and an f, in it"
2,The string in the 2nd row does not have a comma in it
```

## 3. Replacing commas

Even if you deal with the quotes, wouldn't replacing commans get rid of the field delimiter?